# How to import data from SQL Database?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pycharm

I connect local database to app then I want to bring these data into app again to be edited.  That is my code

```
import sys
import os
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"mahmoudtarek.ui"))

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Main,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.InitUI()
        self.conn = None

        self.handle_buttons()
        self.handle_db_connections()

    def InitUI(self):
        ## changes in the run time
        pass

    def handle_buttons(self):
          ## all buttons in the app
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_mahmoud_friends)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.update_mahmoud_friends)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.delete_mahmoud_friends)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.search_mahmoud_friends)


    def handle_db_connections(self):
        try:
            self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='127.0.0.1',
                database='mydb',
                user='root',
                password='134668691011',
                use_pure=True)  # use_pure is set to true

            if self.conn.is_connected():
                db_Info = self.conn.get_server_info()
                print("Connected to MySQL database using C extension... MySQL Server version on ", db_Info)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Error while connecting to MySQL using C extension", err)

    def add_mahmoud_friends(self):
        mth_friends = self.lineEdit.text()
        mth_search = self.lineEdit_4.text()
        if self.conn:
            c = self.conn.cursor()
            try:
                c.execute('''INSERT INTO ahmed (mth_friends,mth_search) values (%s,%s)''', (mth_friends,mth_search))
                self.conn.commit()
                self.lineEdit.setText('')
                self.lineEdit_4.setText('')
                self.statusBar.showMessage('ok mahmoud')


            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                print("Error: ", err)

    def update_mahmoud_friends(self):
        pass

    def delete_mahmoud_friends(self):
        pass
    def search_mahmoud_friends(self):

        sql = '''SELECT * FROM ahmed WHERE mth_search = %s'''
        mth_search = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        self.conn.cursor.execute(sql , [(mth_search)])
        data = self.conn.fetchall()
        for row in data :
            print(row)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.close()
        super(Main, self).closeEvent(event)


def main():
    app= QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error appears here when I import data by printing row in my SQL Database.

Error

> Connected to MySQL database using C extension... MySQL Server version
>   on  8.0.12 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/mahmoudtarek/Desktop/mth1/index.py", line 73, in
>   search_mahmoud_friends
>       self.conn.cursor.execute(sql , [(mth_search)]) AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute'
>
> so, can it be solved or there is another method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Comment: iam still beginner in that field , I want someone edit my code above so, I can learn that also

Comment: You did it correctly in `add_mahmoud_friends`, why don't you look up the right way from there?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change line 73 to

```
self.conn.cursor().execute(sql , [(mth_search)])
```

Comment: Further to the explanation, `cursor` is a function that needs to be called to return an object, its not an cursor object itself, hence needing to call it.

Comment: You need to `fetchall()` from the cursor and not from the connection.

Comment: I added answer below of my current code but still problem with fetchall() method

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try something like below

```
import pymssql
cnxn = pymssql.connect(server='Server_name',user='UID', password='Password', database='Db Name')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()    
cmd = (r"<Your Query>")
cursor.execute(cmd)
query_results = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

Result will be available in query_results

Comment: I will try but can you modify code in my below answer as I do not want to use 2 modules of sql in my code. I am using (mysql connector )

Answer (score 1):

> I solved it thank you all

```
  def search_mahmoud_friends(self):
        if self.conn:
            c = self.conn.cursor()

            try:

                sql = '''SELECT * FROM ahmed WHERE mth_search = %s'''
                mth_search = self.lineEdit_3.text()
                c.execute(sql, [(mth_search)])
                data = c.fetchall()
                for row in data :
                    print(row)

            except mysql.connector.Error as err:
              print("Error: ", err)
```

Comment: This: `[(mth_search)]` should rather read `(mth_search,)` (note the trailing comma). I guess you only made that a list because your DB driver complained about the parameter not being a sequence. That was because if you do `(mth_search)` (without comma) this is treated as literal, not as tuple. Also, please delete your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52362661/4134674). As it stands, it is wrong, and you should not add an answer for every iteration of your solution.