# Is there a way to connect to the online mysql database using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to connect my Python 3 script to my online database so that i can fetch and make changes to the data on the online database. I am a bit new to Python.

Comment: use `pymysql` or multitude of other sql modules.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/372885/5520354

Comment: From C14L's link, I recommend: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51626041/3271649

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Comment: Pymysql throws an error " pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'uxxxxxxx'@'49.249.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)") "

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75639931/6013016)

Answer (score 0):

You can find one possible way [here](https://opensourceforu.com/2009/05/database-programming-in-python/), Database Programming in Python at OpenSource. 
Another one is [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-connecting-mysql-databases/), Python Connecting to MySQL Databases at mySQL Tutorial.

And you can try [this](https://gist.github.com/kirang89/7161185), script by kirang89 on GitHub.

Welcome to the community. If you give us your code where you attempted to do this with a specific issue you are trying to solve, you will get a much better guidance and solution. Ina meanwhile, try to find a similar already answered question.

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75639931/6013016)