# How to Install My-SQL-python in PyCharm using flask especially in Windows

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, mysql-python

Error says:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

[image]

Not only this, am trying to make awesome interactive CRUD project using flask mini framework, but tried as much as hard as possible, i never get a chance to learn or deploy the project, Please anybody help me on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from your proposed solution, you are using `python 3.7` while library you are trying to install is only for version below **2.7** . From their documentation, it's on their *TODO* list and it will only support version **2.7 - 3.3**.

> A 1.3.0 release that will support Python 2.7-3.3

If you need to connect to MYSQL using python, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/9871463).