# Connect to a mysql source in Cloud Dataflow without requirements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there a package that is currently installed in the [Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies) that would allow me to connect to a mysql source? If not, I'll need to add in a requirements.txt file, which I'm trying to eliminate, as it drastically increases the setup time for things.

Update: I suppose `pandas` can, though I believe it needs an additional 'binding' for each sql source it connects to if I'm not mistaken?.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to connect to MySQL you need a specific client that will establish a channel between you and the database. Therefore, you will have to use the `requirements.txt` file to install this library.

You can refer to this [StuckOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) that has a similar question. The answer specifies that "`You must install a MySQL driver before doing anything. Unlike PHP, Only the SQLite driver is installed by default with Python. ...`".

So only the SQLite driver is installed with Python SDK, not the MySQL one.