# How to get access to django database from other python program?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have django project in which I can display records from raspberry pi device. I had mysql database and i have send records from raspberry there. I can display it via my api, but I want to work on this records.I want to change this to django database but I don't know how I can get access to django database which is on VPS server from raspberry pi device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALERT: THIS CAN LEAD TO SECURITY ISSUES**

A Django database is no different from any other database. In this case a MySQL.

The VPS server where the MySQL is must have a public IP, the MySQL must be listening on that IP (if the VPS has a public IP but MySQL is not listening/bind on that IP, it won't work) and the port of the MySQL open (default is 3306), then you can connect to that database from any program with the required configurations params (host, port, user, password,...).

I'm not a sysadmin expert, but having a MySQL on a public IP is a security hole. So the best approach IMO is to expose the operations you want to do via API with Django.