# Monitor database and ssh connection parallel to the rest of the code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a python script, that is fechting data from an sql server. The queries run a long time, and sometimes the skript breaks, because the db or ssh connection is lost. In this situation, the script will freeze, because it is waiting for a result that is never comeing.

Is there a strategy to continuously moinitor if the db connection is still available, while the rest of the script is doing something else (like waiting for the query result)?

How would i even approach this problem, because the monitoring process would have to be decoupled from the rest of the script.

I know, this is a really broad question that might not have an absolute answer, but i hope for some advice for a general aproach that i can read into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by putting your long running code in a separate [thread](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html), and then instead of using `thread.join()` to detect when the thread has finished, you would periodically poll to see if the thread has finished and to see if the connection is still good. The `thread.exit()` function can then be used if you discover that the connection is bad, and you need to exit early.

I was going off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) for the MySQL functions, but you may have to change that out for whatever database you are using. My computer isn't setup to be able to easily connect to a database in Python, so I haven't tested any of this code, so there may be some bugs in it, but this should give you the general idea of how you can monitor a database connection while performing a query.

```
import threading
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","testdb" )

class DB_Query(threading.Thread):
    ''' Used by the run_query function to run a query in a separate thread '''
     def __init__(self, conn, query, dictionary_to_store_results):
         super(DB_Query, self).__init__()
         dictionary_to_store_results['finished'] = false
         self.conn = conn
         self.query = query
         self.result = dictionary_to_store_results

     def run(self):
         cursor = self.conn.cursor()
         try:
             cursor.execute(self.query)
         except SystemExit:
             cleanup_after_unexpected_broken_connection()
             raise
         self.result['data'] = cursor.fetchall()
         self.result['finished'] = true

    def cleanup_after_unexpected_broken_connection():
        # add cleanup code here
        pass

def check_connection_good(conn):
    # check if the connection is good here
    return True

def run_query(query):
    ''' Runs a query, while periodically checking to make sure the connection stays active throughout the process '''
    global conn
    query_result = {} # the thread will populate this dictionary with the results of executing the query
    thread = DB_Query(conn, query, query_result)
    thread.start()
    while(true):
        # check once every half second for the next 5 seconds if the thread is still running
        for i in range(5):
            time.sleep(.5)
            if not thread.is_alive():
                break
        # throw a systemExit error in the thread if the connection is broken
        if not check_connection_good(conn):
            thread.exit()
    return query_result['data']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_query('select * from some_table')
```