# the longtext column is too long to insert，insert into xxx(,,sql) values(,,sql)

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert longtext columns into a table，using python.

I have a columns from `sql` which is too long to be inserted. When I try, it doesn't throw an exception, and my `max_allowed_packet` is longer than the longtext column.

**Example code:** `os.system(mysqlquery+"insert into xxx(sql,,) values(,,,)" % (sql,,))`

When I shorten the sql, it can be inserted:

- the length of sql: 162,072
- max_packet_size:

  - `max_allowed_packet`: 419,4304
  - `slave_max_allowed_packet`: 1,073,741,824

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? Your quoted error message is nothing mysql should say, so it is hard to diagnose what exactly caused it. I am not entirely sure how you run your command, but it might be more a limit of `os.system` (see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120642)) (which is in the general range of your 162k limit). In general, you may want to try a [python connector package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372885) to access your database.

Comment: no error message,I use "os.system('mysql -h -u -p -e "insert into xxx() values()"')"  in a .py file to insert. only 1 row cant be inserted,  beacause its longtext column is too long，only if I shorten the longtext column，it can be inserted.how can i insert this row.