# Data Sharing between WAMP MySQL and Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, wamp, mysql-python, wampserver

I need a way to connect my databases in `WAMP` server `MySQL 5.7` to `Python 3.8` .

I use `MySQL 8.0` in my computer. I am facing the issue in **another** system where there is no MySQL but only `WAMP` server `MySQL 5.7`

Which Module should I be using?

I tried installing `mysql.connector` module in the **other system** but learnt later on that it supports `MySQL 8.0` downloaded from
[www.mysql.org](http://www.mysql.org) only.

Which module should be installed for a satisfactory connection with `WAMP` server `MySQL` and `Python 3.8`?

My code works perfectly without any issues in **my computer** with the normal `MySQL 8.0`.

I have figured out a solution for `Python 2` which is by using the module `MySQLdb`. But it does not support `Python 3`.
I wish to know if there are **other** modules than these

I am sorry for being hasty, but I wish to receive an answer at the earliest. My 
project depends on it. Thank You in advance.

Comment: @Sargis Gevorgyan  Thank You For your edit proposal

Comment: So which version of MySQL are you using in WAMPServer, there are not many recent versions that you cannot install in WAMPServer

Comment: mysql version is 5.7 in wampserver but 8.0 normally..Hope it helps

Comment: So download the version of MySQL you want to use, there are lots of addons availaible. See [The backup repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) Its easier to navigate than the SourceForge mess

Comment: Actually my code works perfectly in my computer.  The issue is faced in another system in my school where only `WAMP` is installed.

Comment: I am aware that `WAMP` has released a `MySQL 8.0` version but I just can not ask my school teachers to install new updates for the computer in my school.

Comment: So is this any use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208181/discussion-between-power-niru-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 1):

I am grateful you came here!

Actually there was a DLL error linked to `WAMP`.
Once I rectified it, I reinstalled `pymysql` through `pip`.

Now `pymysql` works just fine. Make sure you have the right dll files installed in your computer.

Use `mysql` module for the default **MySQL**

Use `pymysql` module for **WAMP**.

Also notice the difference in syntax for the two modules:

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect('host', 'username', 'password')
dbcur = db.cursor()
```

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(username='username', passwd='password',
                             host='host', database = 'dbname')
dbcur = db.cursor()
```