# In Pycharm editor MySQL Command "Show databases " not returning results nor error after run?

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

After running the following code, no results are coming from the MySQL command:

```py
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Abhi@123")

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

    for x in mycursor:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959654/7420301

Maybe try something like this...

```py
import mysql.connector mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                              user="root",
                              password="Abhi@123")
try:
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

    all_my_databases = mycursor.fetchall()

    print all_my_databases

finally:
    mydb.close()
```