# Python database connection for user login

Tags: python, sql, database, forms

How do you create a database and connect one to a python app. I am trying to make a sign up and login feature that saves login data. This is for a project.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This site is not intended for "How do I do this?" questions.  If you've made an attempt and it's not working, you can edit your post and show us.  We'll be able to take a look then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose which database to use first.
If you have selected a database, please install the appropriate package and use an example of linking the database.

Below is an example related to mysql, so please refer to it.
[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)