# mysql doesn't connect to the database python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ubuntu

So when I run this python script on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = '',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='test')
cnx.close()
```

it gives me the following error :
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
Any ideas ?

Comment: Obviously the connection states user: `test` where you show config with user: `root` , so somewhere there's something configured wrong.

Comment: Did you do any research, or red the DOCs ? [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python?rq=1) can help

Answer (score 0):

check your user details using `mysql.user table`. You probably have an anonymous user ''@'localhost' or ''@'127.0.0.1'. so drop this user/create again or create new user.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem(sort of) by uninstalling `mysql` server and installing `mariadb` instead.
although this is probably just avoiding the problem and not fixing it. It worked for me.