# List of employee whose salary is greater than manager using Python code?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I wrote the code in MY SQL

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employees w,
     employees m
WHERE w.manager_id = m.emp_id
  AND w.salary> m.salary;
```

My question is how will I execute the same question using Python?

Comment: I would question why, you would do this. SQL is best suited for answering questions like this. SQL is optimized for set oriented queries, like the one you have asked now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector as ms
mycon = ms.connect(host = "<localhostmostly>", user = "<yourusernameinSQL>", passwd = "<yourpwd>", database = "<yourdbname>")
mycursor = mycon.cursor()

query = '''SELECT *
FROM employees w,
     employees m
WHERE w.manager_id = m.emp_id
  AND w.salary> m.salary;'''

mycursor.execute(query)
```

This is the solution to your problem. If you want to print the results in Python, then write this line after the previously written code.

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresult)
```

Hope this solved your problem! If you are writing the query in Python in a single line, do not use triple quotes (you will mostly be knowing that, but I thought I should say).

Comment: thanks, Arya, but actually my question { 'emp_id':1.'emp_name':X,Sal=1000,Manager_name=y, manager_id=5}......How will iterate over these rows to find a list of employees whose sal is greater than their manager?

Comment: Are you having the rows as a dictionary? And if possible can you attack your table so that I can tell you a better solution?

Comment: Your table as in the way you are storing it in Python.. Like a dictionary, a list or however you are storing the values

Comment: Instead of creating a data frame, I'm showing a dictionary with a key-value pair for the employee table